# When uploading a lot of products admin hangs but can be accessed from different browser

Tags: magento-1.9, indexing, admin-panel

We have dedicated server with 6 cores and over 20GB of ram. 
The problem we have is that after importing products, its not possible to do anything in the admin section. It simply hangs.  If we try different browser than we can get in.

From googling around we found that this is related to indexing.  When we switched indexing to manual, everything is fine. We upload products and admin works normally. Then we manually index everything.  I found some plugins for asynchronous indexing etc. But I'm interested, is there some kind of setting on the server that we can tweak which will allow to have auto indexing on and admin section wont hang  after uploading products ?

Also order processing hangs after products are uploaded.

We went through all mysql settings recommended on the web. But it feels like we are missing something here.

Or this is simply how magento works and we need to deal with it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how magento works. Deal with it :).
It seams to me that you are doing it right. When importing products, the indexes have to be set on "manual". This speeds up the import and the indexing after.